# Run a procedure that uses already defined function in SQL as a boolean

Tags: sql, sql-server

So my issue is that I need the get_behorighet to be run withing the procedure do_uttag. I have checked that get_behorighet returns an int, either 1 or 0. But it does not seem to work however i change the syntax in my procedure.

**The program returns an error when running the function do_uttag.** Foreign keys and other table data seems not to be the issue here.

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure aifer_uttag, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect action
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.do_uttag, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 0]
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted
```

**This is the main procedure**

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE do_uttag(
    @p_radnr int,
    @p_pnr varchar(11),
    @p_knr int,
    @p_belopp numeric(10,2),
    @p_datum date)
AS  
BEGIN
DECLARE @undantag int; 
SET @undantag = (SELECT dbo.get_behorighet(@p_pnr, @p_knr));
PRINT cast(@undantag AS int)
IF @undantag = 1 
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO uttag (radnr, pnr, knr, belopp, datum)
    VALUES (@p_radnr, @p_pnr, @p_knr, @p_belopp, @p_datum);

    UPDATE konto
    SET saldo = (saldo - @p_belopp)
    WHERE knr = @p_knr;

    declare @saldo numeric(10,2) = (select saldo from konto where knr = @p_knr);
    PRINT 'Totalt saldo efter uttag: ' + CAST(@saldo AS VARCHAR(20));
    END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Uttag misslyckades';
END
END
```

**This is the function that return 1 or 0**

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION get_behorighet(
@p_pnr varchar(11),
@p_knr int)
RETURNS INT  
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @konto_value INT
    /* uttag */
    IF EXISTS (SELECT k.knr, ka.pnr FROM konto k, kontoagare ka WHERE (k.knr = @p_knr) AND (ka.pnr = @p_pnr))
    BEGIN
    SET @konto_value = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    SET @konto_value = 0
    END
    RETURN @konto_value
    END
GO
```

**For easier understanding of the problem that I am facing I have added an image of the database design.**

[image]

Comment: So you have a trigger defined on the table. It stops you from doing a wrong thing. We don't know what it thinks is wrong.

Comment: An error like *"The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted"* suggests as well that the `TRIGGER` has a `ROLLBACK` in it. Ideally you should avoid putting a `ROLLBACK` in the `TRIGGER` and should be `THROW`ing an error; then you can handle the error outside the trigger (such as by performing a `ROLLBACK` and further `THROW`ing that error to the application).

Comment: @JoakimEngqvist . . . I suspect that you can do what you want without functions and triggers, using constraints.  You might consider asking a *new* question and explaining what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What's in the `aifer_uttag` proc that generated the first error?

Comment: NO ONE should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: And you should not be using PRINT in production code - especially when that procedure is used by a trigger. Triggers should not attempt to return resultsets.